# Auto populate SharePoint column from Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, azure-ad

I have a SharePoint list with a column called 'Name' (Person/Group type) where you can select a name from Active Directory.

I have then set up JSON formatting to auto populate the Email column. I'm using the following code:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "[$Name.email]"
}
```

I would also like the Office Location to be auto populating in a similar way, but I cannot achieve this by modifying the above code. My proper name for that location column is:

```
Faculty_x0020__x002f__x0020_CPS
```

Would you have any advice? How do I reference the 'Office Location' Active Directory entry?

Comment: Are you trying to bring active directory property (Office Location) in list using JSON formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint JSON formatting **does not support** showing "Office Location" property from Azure AD for person or group column.

The people field object supports the following properties only in JSON formatting (with example values):

```
{
  "id": "122",
  "title": "Kalya Tucker",
  "email": "kaylat@contoso.com",
  "sip": "kaylat@contoso.com",
  "picture": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/kaylat_contoso_com_MThumb.jpg?t=63576928822",
  "department":"Human Resources",
  "jobTitle":"HR Manager"
}
```

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON formatting - Special string values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#special-string-values)